# How do I make my image change to another image on hover

Tags: html, image, css, class, hover

Can anyone help me out ? I'm trying to make my logo to change into another image when on hover.

```
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/base.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/modele01.css"/>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" >
     <title> Look At Them Cars </title>
     <style type='text/css'> 
        img {
            background-image: url('./images/LogoSite.png');
        }

        img:hover {
            background-image: url('./images/LogoBleu.png');
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="titre" class="slide header">
        <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="./images/LogoSite.png"></a></h1>
        <br></br>
        <div id="liste">
            <a href="Lexus">Lexus</a>
            <a href="Porsche">Porsche</a>
            <a href="Toyota">Toyota</a>
            <a href="Crédits">Crédits</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've been trying to do a class in my css img:hover with the background-image that I want to change to it. It didn't work

Comment: <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="./images/LogoSite.png"></a></h1>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any additional information you'd like to include.

Answer (score 0):

Using the background image property approach, try this at the top of your html page in the head tag:

```
<style type='text/css'> 
    img {
       background-image: url('firstimage.png');
    }

    img:hover {
       background-image: url('second.png');
    }
</style>
```